# Linq Query Exception when filtering data

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I want to filter enrolled and unenrolled courses by traineeid. In here there are 3 tables in the db Trainee(ID,TraineeName),Course(ID,CourseName),TraineeCourseEnrollment(TraineeID,CourseID,ENrolledDate). I can simply query enrolled courses but it is difficult to query unenrolled courses. Here is my code...

```
    public IEnumerable<CourseDTO> GetCourse(string traineeid, bool isenrolled)
    {


        List<Course> enrolled=new List<Course>();
        List<CourseDTO> course_enrolled_dtos= new List<CourseDTO>();
        List<CourseDTO> course_unenrolled_dtos = new List<CourseDTO>();

        IEnumerable<TraineeCourseEnrollment> enrolled_courses = db.Trainees.Find(traineeid).TraineeCourseEnrollments.ToList();
        foreach (TraineeCourseEnrollment enroll in enrolled_courses)
        {
            course_enrolled_dtos.Add(new CourseDTO() { CourseName = enroll.Course.CourseName, ID = enroll.Course.ID });
            enrolled.Add(new Course() { CourseName = enroll.Course.CourseName, ID = enroll.Course.ID });
        }

        if(isenrolled)
        {
            return course_enrolled_dtos;
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable<Course> unenrolled=db.Courses.Except(enrolled); 
            foreach (Course unenroll in unenrolled)//Exception
            {
                course_unenrolled_dtos.Add(new CourseDTO() { CourseName = unenroll.CourseName, ID = unenroll.ID });
            }
            return course_enrolled_dtos;
        }




    }
```

This code giving an exception

> *Unable to create a constant value of type 'DAL_EF1.Course'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

In here is there any best way to query this data using Linq extention methods.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: foreach (Course unenroll in unenrolled) this line getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is in here:

```
IEnumerable<Course> unenrolled=db.Courses.Except(enrolled);
```

You are trying to filter your data through the object. Instead, you can try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Course> unenrolled=db.Courses.Where(c => !enroller.Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Not yet solved c => !enroller.Contains(c.ID) should be in like this c => !enroller.Contains(c) but it also getting same error

Comment: Actually this is the problem itself. When you do c => !enroller.Contains(c), you are trying to filter through the object itself which when linq convert this to sql it fails to translate c. This is exactly why you are getting "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context." exception because c is not primitive type, it's an object.

Comment: You need to filter your data by object's properties. In this case, your object is Course. So you need to try building your query by using Course properties.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that entity framework only allow premitive types in filter.

Try this.

Replace,

```
    IEnumerable<Course> unenrolled=db.Courses.Except(enrolled);
```

with,

```
       var enrolledID = enrolled.Select(e => e.CourseID).ToList();
       IEnumerable<Course> unenrolled=db.Courses.Where(c => !enrolledID.Contains(c.CourseID));
```